# laravel. echo variable to view from controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have some Ajax making a post request to a function in my controller (postIndex)
I would like to echo this variable ($a) to the view.

```
public function postIndex( \Illuminate\Http\Request $request ){
/*
* CODE
*/
$a = "string";
echo $a;

return SOMETHING;
}
```

Comment: if you action with ajax you get response with ajax too , so edit your question and insert ajax code to get response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't echo directly from a controller, if you are making an AJAX request you need to return an AJAX response, then on your view you can manage your response as you like.

The controller action would look like this:

```
public function postIndex( \Illuminate\Http\Request $request ){
  /*
  * CODE
  */
  $a = "string";

  return response($a);
}
```

This is how your AJAX in your view should look like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "//your AJAX route",
    type: "post", //send it through post method
    data: { 
      //send your data here 
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response); // Your response.
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      console.log("ERROR"+xhr); // Debug errors.
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a simpler / faster way to do this? Feels like this would get a bit annoying to do every time you have to debugging. Thank you!

Comment: @oskarz53 This is the proper way to do it because you know how to response would look after a real AJAX request :/